# How to fill color in a svg image plotted with annotation_custom?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I currently load a svg and plot it in ggplot2 but I haven't so far figured how to change the color of the black and white svg file. Maybe I'm using the wrong API?

```
library(grid)
library(grImport2)

envelopeGrob <- gTree(children=gList(pictureGrob(readPicture("inst/svg/envelope2.svg"))))
```

and then:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + theme_clean() + annotation_custom(envelopeGrob, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

There is no color or fill input in any of the functions involved. Is there a way?

Comment: it's going to place the image. is the svg in black & white? if so, then the svg will be placed as such. change the original SVG to the colors that you need

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thank you. Yes I used what you suggest and works but it would be great some form of changing the color and fill at runtime ... otherwise would need to create multiple svgs or potentially many permutations ...

Comment: you can read in the SVG programmatically with `xml2`, make the necessary node attribute changes (i.e. modify the colors using the facilities provided by `xml2`) and write out the modified file for inclusion.

Comment: grImport2 has various examples; [here's one](https://sjp.co.nz/projects/grimport2/grImport2.html) (look at the 'customisation' section)

Comment: btw is there such a thing as `library(pictureGrob)`?

Comment: @baptiste You are right Sir sorry copy-paste error :D

Comment: Other nice examples by Murrell & Potter [here](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Reports/leaf/leaf.html), using `gridSVG`

Comment: @baptiste your `grImport2` comment customization section solves the OP :) thank you! wanna do a proper answer?